# Syntax Error after cut and paste SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have checked all things in related to internet all are same as they say i just cant understand what is wrong, Please help me early.

```
//stored procedure
    DELIMITER $$

    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `manoj`.`SP_inserttbluserregistration` $$
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`syits04-pc` PROCEDURE 
    `SP_inserttbluserregistration`(IN FIRSTNAME1 varchar(500),IN LASTNAME1 
    varchar(500),IN EMAIL1 varchar(500),IN USERTYPE1 integer,IN USERNAME1 
    varchar(500),IN PASSWORD1 varchar(500),IN STATUS1 INTEGER,IN UPDATESTATUS1 
    INTEGER,IN DELETESTATUS1 INTEGER)
    BEGIN
    insert into 
  tbluserregistration(FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,USERTYPE,USERNAME,PASSWORD,STATUS,UPDATESTATUS,DELETESTATUS) VALUES(FIRSTNAME1,LASTNAME1,EMAIL1,USERTYPE1,USERNAME1,PASSWORD1,STATUS1,UPDATESTATUS1,DELETESTATUS1);
END $$
```

DELIMITER ;

// this is code of c#

```
MySqlCommand cmdi = new MySqlCommand("SP_inserttbluserregistration", GetConnection.GetConnectionOpen());
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FIRSTNAME1", FIRSTNAME);
                    cmd.Parameters["FIRSTNAME1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LASTNAME1", LASTNAME);
                    cmd.Parameters["LASTNAME1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("USERTYPE1", USERTYPE);
                    cmd.Parameters["USERTYPE1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMAIL1", EMAIL);
                    cmd.Parameters["EMAIL1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("USERNAME1", USERNAME);
                    cmd.Parameters["USERNAME1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PASSWORD1", PASSWORD);
                    cmd.Parameters["PASSWORD1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("STATUS1", 0);
                    cmd.Parameters["STATUS1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UPDATESTATUS1", 0);
                    cmd.Parameters["UPDATESTATUS1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DELETESTATUS1", 0);
                    cmd.Parameters["DELETESTATUS1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    object isInserted = cmdi.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (isInserted != null)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

ERROR

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SP_inserttbluserregistration' at line 1

Comment: Try prefixing param names with @ E.g. `..AddWithValue("@FIRSTNAME1", ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quote marks (`) are wrong. Sometimes when you cut and paste, the incorrect characters are used. Try replace all the (') characters with (') instead of (`)